# What control should I use to display visual, manipulable elements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, controls

I want to develop a level editor using visual studio 2013 and c#. I know c/c++ but am new to C# and want to start simple. I want to use a control that will allow me to handle events from the mouse (get clicks, click release, get position inside the control, etc) and also that it will allow me to draw inside of it (simple rectangles should be enough for now).

A picture control sounds intuitive but doesn't seem right since it is a static control. What is the proper control I should use for these purposes?

Comment: Which platform do you target: WPF, Winforms, ASP...?

Comment: It is supposed to be a desktop application so the answer is I don't know. I am currently trying on WPF with canvas as suggested by James.

Comment: 'simple rectangles should be enough for now' Do plan for growth! So a more or less full list of thing will eventually want to do is much better than starting out too small. Levels can be made up of tiles of of one piece; may have one layer or several.. Do make a more detailed plan!!

Comment: Thanks for the design lesson, but as I said, I'll be fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting place would probably be a Canvas. It gives you an X-Y based surface onto which you can draw shapes and primitives.